comparar con query builder en laravel
estoy trabajando con query builder en laravel. intento comparar la cantidad con el numero de veces que aparece en diferentes consecutivos del objeto arreglo procedimientos, que tengan el mismo numero de autorizacion y codigo tecnologia, pero solo me itera una vez el arreglo, como si solo tuviera un dato en la tabla, que puedo hacer?
                        foreach ($datos['usuarios'] as $usuario) {
                            if (isset($usuario['servicios']['procedimientos'])) {
                                foreach ($usuario['servicios']['procedimientos'] as $procedimiento) {
                                    $numAutorizacion = $procedimiento['numAutorizacion'];
                                    $codProcedimiento = $procedimiento['codProcedimiento'];

                                    $combinacionActual = $numAutorizacion . '-' . $codProcedimiento;
                                    if (!isset($combinacionesProcesadas[$combinacionActual]) && $numAutorizacion === $num_autorizacion && $codProcedimiento === $cod_procedimiento) {

                                        $contador++;
                                        $combinacionesProcesadas[$combinacionActual] = true;


                                    }
                                }
                            }
                        }


                        $cantidadAutorizada = DB::table('autorizaciones')
                            ->where([['numero_autorizacion', $num_autorizacion], ['codigo_tecnologia', $cod_procedimiento]])
                            ->select('cantidad')
                            ->first();

                            $cantidad = intval($cantidadAutorizada->cantidad);


                            ConexionDB::cambiarBaseDeDatos('aud_db_' . $nit);
                            $vrServicio = DB::table('procedimientos')
                                ->where([['num_autorizacion', $num_autorizacion], ['cod_procedimiento', $cod_procedimiento]])
                                ->select('vr_servicio')
                                ->first();

                            ConexionDB::restablecerBaseDeDatos();


                        if ($cantidad < $contador && $numAutorizacion === $num_autorizacion && $codProcedimiento === $cod_procedimiento) {

                            $diferencia = $contador - $cantidad;
                           
                            $vrServicio = intval($vrServicio->vr_servicio);

                            $vrServicio = $diferencia * $vrServicio;

                            $glosa[] = 'IDENTIFICACIÓN: ' . $identificacionUsuario . ' - ' . 'CONSECUTIVO: ' . $consecutivo . ' - ' . $mensaje->mensaje . ' - ' . 'VALOR: ' . $vrServicio;
                            dd($glosa);
                        } 


Al ponerle ->first() te está trayendo solamente una fila. Si quieres todas las filas de esa consulta, debes cambiarlo por get().
